# <fb:login-button> attributes&events

Tags: javascript, html, fbml

How do I get a complete list with all attributes and events for fb:login-button?
There are many attributes (eg: "perms") or events (eg: "onlogin").

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a problem with that:  The Facebook JS replaces  with valid HTML.  So once the pageload is complete, the element is gone, replaced with a bunch of `<div>`s and `<span>`s and `<a>`s.  No attributes for you.

However, you might be able to do something with the HTML that's generated.  Here's a sample:

```
<div class="connect_widget">
    <a class="fb_button fb_button_small" onclick="ConnectLogin.login(null, &quot;&quot;); return false;" href="#">
        <span class="fb_button_text">Log In</span>
    </a>
    <div class="clearfix profile_images_without_margin">
        <div class="uiFacepile uiFacepileMedium">
            <ul class="uiList uiListHorizontal clearfix">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would experiment around with different attributes on `<fb:login-button>` and see how that changes the HTML.

Comment: Thx, Theron. I need to know what attributes/events can I use for my code.